# r - raster package inefficient use of memory or r limitation on some raster operations?

Tags: r, r-raster

This is basically the same issue found in this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95481/in-r-set-na-cells-in-one-raster-where-another-raster-has-values and here [R - Chaging specific cell values in a large raster layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617176/r-chaging-specific-cell-values-in-a-large-raster-layer). The answers in the first question did not solve my problem because I do not have another object that I can use with `overlay` or `calc`. Reclassify is the only thing that works.

in my case, I have a a raster file which is 300 MB. I am applying a simple operation, just trying to replace all values in the raster that are equal to a certain number with NAs. I have about 4 GB of RAM available, but it seems I cannot complete this operation because I get the error "cannot allocate vector of size 4.6 GB". I have tried even setting my memory size to 16 GB but then I get the same error just saying that cannot allocate vector of size 9.2 GB.
I have tried the following two options:

```
r[r==5]=NA 
values(r)[values(r)==5]
```

strangely, even a simple operation such as table(values(r)) gives the same error, for example ArcMap can create this table in a few seconds. I have already solved my problem but I am wondering why this huge inefficiency of memory use and how can it be prevented or avoided? Why is `raster` requiring up to 9 GB to process a file that is 300 MB? Is this a limitation of this package or with R?

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid loading all values into memory by using raster package functions instead. For example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[] <- sample(5, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Instead of `table(values(r))` use `freq`:

```
freq(r)
```

Change value 5 to NA. Either with `reclassify` of with `subs`

```
x <- reclassify(r, data.frame(from=5, to=NA))
y <- subs(r, data.frame(from=5, to=NA), subsWithNA=FALSE)

freq(x)
```

lbusset suggests `calc` and that should also work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works for these operations, but R freezes also when I use distance and direction.

Comment: I have no idea what you refer to with "distance and direction"

Comment: I was referring to the `distance` and `direction` functions in the raster package.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem here is that with your approaches you are loading all the raster data in memory, "duplicating" it a couple of times because `r[r==5]=...`  needs to create a copy of r, and also creating large accessory variables (e.g., `r == 5`). Add to this that while importing in R you are automatically "casting" to double and removing any (eventual) compression, and the memory requirements will scale up rapidly.

The problem with `table(values(r))` is the same, because `values(r)` will load all pixels' values in memory.

With moderately large rasters, it is always best to use `calc` or `overlay`, which work by chunks of lines and "swap" to disk if needed. In your case, this (taken directly from `calc` help) should work:

```r
fun <- function(x) {x[x==5] <- NA; return(x) }
r2 <- raster::calc(r, fun)
```

Comment: It is questionable whether the problem is in my approach or in the way the package handles operations.